# A class that accepts an array of objects then adds to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

So below I have a Dog class and a Doghouse class. I'm pretty new to java so I'm a unclear how to create a Doghouse class that has a constructor that accepts an array of Dogs and adds it to an ArrayList. Does the code I have below make any sense?

```
 public class Dog{
   public Dog(int number, double price, double sWeight, String origin, String webpage){
   }
}



import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Doghouse{
private ArrayList<Dog> dogList;

public Doghouse(Dog[] newDog){

    for(int i = 0; i < newDog.length; i++){
        dogList.add(newDog[i]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lack of research

Comment: It will happily throw a `NullPointerException` at you.

Comment: Also what does `public Warehouse` have to do with a Doghouse?

Comment: Minor typo. edited to fit. thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

At present using `dogList` without initializing it would throw an NPE.

You can fix it as:

```
public static class Doghouse {
    private List<Dog> dogList;

    public Doghouse(Dog[] newDog) { // constructor name corrected
        this.dogList = Arrays.stream(newDog).collect(toList());
    }
}
```

or may be simpler to understand

```
public Doghouse(Dog[] newDog) {
    this.dogList = new ArrayList<>(); // initialise first
    dogList.addAll(Arrays.asList(newDog)); // add later
}
```